# Black screen for twenty seconds, then power off on Ubuntu 17.10 and now 18.04 every second time I turn on my laptop

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04, 17.10, shutdown

I upgraded to 17.10 a few weeks back (only OS on the laptop) and am having a recurring problem. When I boot the laptop, I have no BIOS loading (i.e. no Dell logo) and no grub menu displaying on startup. The lights underneath my laptop keys do not turn on either.

After 20 seconds, the power cuts on the laptop and a light at the front of my laptop flashes a few times (alternating between white and orange colour). On the second attempt, the laptop always boots without fail, I get the Dell logo and then the Grub menu for Ubuntu.

This has not happened before my update. Can anyone give me some ideas on how to correctly diagnose the problem and hopefully solve it? I'm hoping my SSD isnt failing or anything.

I AM having a recurring problem where Firefox is randomly crashing and cannot be killed by terminal or by shut down, requiring me to hold down the power button to reboot. I'm wondering if that is what is causing the issue.

EDIT:

Upgraded to 18.04, still having the issue. Here's a few sample from the logs around boot time, I'm not sure what exactly I should look out for. The error occurs before the BIOS or the Grub is booted:

```
[    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
[    0.000000] clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645519600211568 ns
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x99/0x4fd with crng_init=0
[    0.000000] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:8192 nr_cpumask_bits:8 nr_cpu_ids:8 nr_node_ids:1
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 46 pages/cpu @        (ptrval) s151552 r8192 d28672 u262144
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s151552 r8192 d28672 u262144 alloc=1*2097152
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 4091451
[    0.000000] Policy zone: Normal
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic root=UUID=1ecb14d8-0d53-4a81-97b1-7655d3712b47 ro
[    0.000000] Calgary: detecting Calgary via BIOS EBDA area
[    0.000000] Calgary: Unable to locate Rio Grande table in EBDA - bailing!
[    0.000000] Memory: 16164932K/16625676K available (12300K kernel code, 2470K rwdata, 4240K rodata, 2408K init, 2416K bss, 460744K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=8, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Kernel/User page tables isolation: enabled
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 39092 entries in 153 pages
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=8192 to nr_cpu_ids=8.
[    0.000000]  Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=8
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 524544, nr_irqs: 2048, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.000000] ACPI: Core revision 20170831
[    0.000000] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.XHC_.RHUB.HS11] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/dswload-210)
[    0.000000] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170831/psobject-252)
[    0.000000] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, (SSDT:xh_rvp11) while loading table (20170831/tbxfload-228)
[    0.000000] ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 12 successful (20170831/tbxfload-246)
[    0.000000] clocksource: hpet: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 79635855245 ns
[    0.000000] hpet clockevent registered
[    0.004000] APIC: Switch to symmetric I/O mode setup
[    0.004000] DMAR: Host address width 39
[    0.004000] DMAR: DRHD base: 0x000000fed90
```

Answer (score 1):

"Calgary: Unable to locate Rio Grande table in EBDA - bailing!"

I did some research on this error and found that it's talking about IOMMU. Some BIOSes have the ability to turn in on/off. If yours doesn't, you can try to disable it by adding iommu=off to your boot option by hitting "e" at the grub menu. If that fixed the issue; then to add this persistently edit your GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= setting in /etc/default/grub file. You will then need to update grub with: sudo update grub.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem arising out of the forceful shutdown of the system.
Try removing Firefox entirely:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge firefox
```

Then reboot your system and check for the booting pattern the second time around.

If the issue persists, check the last few entries around boot-time for further clues into what device drivers aren't functioning as expected:

```
$ dmesg | tail
```